# Тюрьма города N или тюрьма в городе N?

Tags: управление

Как правильно:тюрьма города N или тюрьма в городе N? В первом случае получается, что тюрьма принадлежит городу. Но говорят, по-моему *театры Москвы*, например.

Answer (score 1):

По нормативности - совершенно равноправные варианты. "Принадлежит" не обязательно, может и просто относится, как и в примере с театрами.

Вот что касается стилистики... Создается впечатление (субъективно), что "тюрьма города" это скорее характеристика самого города. "Тюрьма в городе" - более нейтрально. Хотя опять же, надо смотреть, что за город, одна ли там тюрьма - и вообще контекст.

Comment: контекст такой: заключенный тюрьмы № 137/2 города N жалуется...

Comment: Это меняет дело. В таком контексте тчоность важнее стилистики. 
"заключенный тюрьмы № 137/2, **расположеной** в городе N, жалуется...